# Objective c: Do I have to retype all the code everytime?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm making a server based app. Each time I do a request to the database, I have to type all the server connection code. Is it possible to reuse this somehow? In php, you usually have a file call dbConnect.php (or something similar) that you can call each time you want to connect.

Example, I would like to replace this, which I use all the time:

```
- (void)doSomething
{
__block ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL: url]; 
__weak ASIHTTPRequest *request_b = request;
[request setDelegate: self]; 
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/html; charset=utf-8;"];
[request setDefaultResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
[request setTimeOutSeconds: 10.0f]; 
[request setCachePolicy: ASIDoNotWriteToCacheCachePolicy | ASIDoNotReadFromCacheCachePolicy]; 

 //Set the variables here

    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

... with something like:

```
    - (void)doSomething
    { 
         LoadServerCode;  //This loads all the server code as above

         //Set variables 

         [request startAsynchronous];

    }
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

To clarify a little bit. Say I have some methods I use a lot, like creating a UILabel, or a UIView in a special way... It would be nice not to have to subclass, and end up with a bunch of classes, but rather have one class called MyConstructionMethods or something... So if I want to create a label on some different places in the app, I can just type:

```
MyGreenLabel; //Done, the label is created and added to the view
```

... instead of:

```
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 10)]; 
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; 
    [self.view addSubview: label];
```

Comment: I'm not versatile with php or obj-c but I think I can safely assume that you can have a global variable (or a long scope variable) that holds the connection open for you. At least this is how its done in every other language I've worked in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a macro?

In your .h file:

```
#define LoadServerCode() \
__block ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url]; \
__weak ASIHTTPRequest *request_b = request; \
[request setDelegate: self]; \
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/html; charset=utf-8;"]; \
[request setDefaultResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; \
[request setTimeOutSeconds: 10.0f]; \
[request setCachePolicy: ASIDoNotWriteToCacheCachePolicy | ASIDoNotReadFromCacheCachePolicy];
```

Then, in your implementation:

```
-(void)doSomething {
    LoadServerCode();

    //Set variables

    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that was exactly what I was looking for. Now I can just store the macros in a separate file and quickly reuse them when I need. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you are keeping all your connection classes isolated from the rest of your code, then why cant you just make a method that will create your request set your vars and return the request for you to start async...Even if you are not keep your connection stuff isolated you can still have a static method of some class have this method...

Comment: static method aren't any OOP like, subclassing is the best way.

Answer (score 2):

you could implement your custom ASIHTTPRequest class:

```
@interface YourRequest : ASIFormDataRequest
@end


@implementation YourRequest  

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)newURL {
  self = [super initWithURL: newURL];

  if (self) {
      [self addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/html; charset=utf-8;"];
      [self setDefaultResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
      [self setTimeOutSeconds: 10.0f]; 
      [self setCachePolicy: ASIDoNotWriteToCacheCachePolicy | ASIDoNotReadFromCacheCachePolicy]; 
    }
  }

  return self;
}
@end
```

and create the object:

```
 - (void)doSomething { 
     __block YourRequest *request = [YourRequest requestWithURL: url]; 
     __weak ASIHTTPRequest *request_b = request;
     [request setDelegate : self];
     //Set variables 

     [request startAsynchronous];

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to reuse that setup code multiple times in the same implementation file, consider refactoring with [Extract Method](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) to create a utility method that returns a properly-configured request object.

If you need to do this kind of thing in numerous places, consider subclassing `ASIFormDataRequest` so you can more succinctly create request objects with the properties configured as you most commonly set them. Alternatively, you could create some kind of request factory class with static methods for generating request objects.

Answer (score 1):

you can declare methods in your header file and those will be available when using your class. so you could declare doSomthing in your .h file then implement that method in your .m file and when you want to "doSomthing" just call `[className doSomthing]`
if you want to show more code i can probably give you a better example